# MySQL to PDO error

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following sql code:

```
$statement = "`maildb`";

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$statement}";
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
```

I am trying to transform to PDO... I have tried the following:

```
$statement = "`maildb`";

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$statement}"); 
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That results in: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in function.php on line 8.

I have also tried this before, which should do the same:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM maildb"); 
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$num = count($row);
```

Any help?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $db which is not initialized. Please initialize it first by doing `$db = new PDO( <connection details here> )`. See [PDO manual on PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for more details.

Comment: Hey, thanks, I did initialize it: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mailing;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');

Comment: Then check if it is really initialized (i.e. by doing `var_dump($db);`. If it will not be Object, then check if you got mysql driver for PDO installed. If not, install it and restart your webserver.

Comment: Dumped it and realised it returned NULL, made some changes to the code, and now works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it works. Please accept the answer if I was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't instantiate $db. Therefore, it's not an object, thus you can't call a function from it

Comment: Hey, thanks, I did initialize it: $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mailing;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies in this line:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM {$statement}");
```

Instead try using:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `num` FROM ?");
$query->execute($statement);
```